# Chilling - who am I?

Tags: riddle

```
I am the darkness of the lamp made clear,
the chill of the summer made cloudy.

If I get juiced up, some say I'm a delicacy.
Treat me incautiously, you'll land on your seat.

I may be found the world over,
but I dwell in the depths of Kentucky.

Leave me to myself, headless, and I will fade away.
Give to me a new head, though, and I can do many things:
  I can feed the multitudes, or spend my days gaming.
  I can be kind, or I can be cruel.
  I can even become loathsome vermin, twice over.
```

Who am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> Ice

I am the darkness of the lamp made clear,
the chill of the summer made cloudy.

> Lamp=flame=melting to clear water, chill=cold=freezing to cloudy ice? probably wrong but my best guess

If I get juiced up, some say I'm a delicacy.

> Blended drinks

Treat me incautiously, you'll land on your seat.

> Ice is slippery

I may be found the world over,

> Can be found everywhere

but I dwell in the depths of Kentucky.

> There is an actual city called Ice, Kentucky

Leave me to myself, headless, and I will fade away.
Give to me a new head, though, and I can do many things:

> Ice melts but add a letter to the front and you get

I can feed the multitudes, or spend my days gaming.

> Rice, Dice

I can be kind, or I can be cruel.

> Nice, Vice?

I can even become loathsome vermin, twice over.

> Mice, Lice

Comment: You didn't get my answer for the darkness part, but otherwise very well done!